# User Control cannot be accessed by another CS file

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, namespaces

There is a `UserControlA` which was already developed when I joined on a project. It is in a  Project which I will call `MyProjectWeb` and it's namespace is `MyProjectWeb.Common`.

```
namespace MyProjectWeb.Common
{
    public partial class UserControlA : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {

...
```

There is another WorkFlowManager project that contains a class file which accesses this UserControl1.

```
MyProjectWeb.Common.UserControlA myUserControlA = (MyProjectWeb.Common.UserControlA)WizardControl.FindControl("TabContainer5$tpSomething$UserControlID");
```

**Note: WorkFlowManager and MyProjectWeb are in the same solution.**

This works completely fine. And now I want to create another UserControl which is UserControlB.

I followed the exact same thing.

```
namespace MyProjectWeb.Common
{
    public partial class UserControlB : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
```

But to my surprise, I cannot create an instance of UserControlB in the same code file in WorkFlowManager. MyProjectWeb.Common namespace does not even contain a UserControlB. When I compile I get obviously get a
`The type or namespace name 'UserControlB' does not exist in the namespace 'MyProjectWeb.Common' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

Why is that I can reference UserControlA but not UserControlB which are in the same namespace from the WorkFlowManager cs file? If I access the MyProjectWeb.Common namespace  anywhere inside the MyProjectWeb, I can see both the user controls. Anywhere to look for errors?

I am using Visual Studio 2005 with ASP .NET 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would depend upon how *WorkFlowManager* project references *MyProjectWeb* dll. If both projects are in same solution, then it should have been a project reference but you need to verify it. If the reference is made to dll file then you need to see where exactly the referenced file is stored - my guess is that *WorkFlowManager* project is referencing a private copy of *MyProjectWeb* dll that obviously does not get updated when you rebuild MyProjectWeb.

Comment: WorkFlowManager is referencing an old dll file just like you said. :) But my issue is that Web Projects do not create dll files do they? If yes, where can I find the latest updated dll file?

Comment: @Ranhiru, web application project will create dll files - they will be located in bin directory under your web project root directory.

Comment: Thanx a lot mate :) `WorkFlowManager.csproj` file had a reference to a wrong dll file. Removing the reference from VS 2005 and re-adding the correct dll just kept still kept referring to the same DLL! Had to manually edit the csproj file. Thanx heaps!

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to look at the project to know for sure, what you're saying above doesn't tell me quite enough.

Quick ideas:

- Make sure that UserControlB.cs is actually in the right project.
- Make sure that UserControlB.cs is marked as "Compile" for the build type.
- Make sure that UserControlB is actually "B" not "A" because, since they're partial, a spelling error could cause them to combine together.
- Those user controls are "partial" did you also copy the other part?
- Make sure the web project doesn't have any errors, it's possible that the project isn't being built correctly and the error you're getting is because of a stale assembly.
- Clean + Rebuild. Delete bin and obj directories manually.